# javax.mail.transport not sending alert for 1000 or 1000+ active email ids

Tags: java

I can send a message to exact 999 active users and also email alerts to same in my application but can send the only message to 1000 or more than 1000 active users and not the email alerts. I am using javax.mail.transport class to send the email alerts.
While debugging I can see all the users with their respective email ids in toAddresses but after transport.send(msg) statement control goes off and their won't be an exception and also alerts don't get sent if toAddresses contains 1000 or 1000+ active email ids.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
if (toList != null && toList.size() > 0) {
toAddresses = new InternetAddress[toList.size()];
toList.copyInto(toAddresses);
}

Message msg = prepareHeader(smtp_host, from, toAddresses, null, null,
subject,header);
MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart text = new MimeBodyPart();
msg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
text.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
text.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");
text.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);
text.setContent(appendHTMLStartEnd(message), "text/html; charset=utf-8");
mp.addBodyPart(text);

try
{
Transport.send(msg);
}
catch (SendFailedException ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
throw ex;
}
```

Comment: This does not seems to be the issue in your code. To me it seems the problem is at your mailing server end. there probably is some threshold limit set at your mailing server you are using

Comment: @Ankur : I checked on SMTP server and it has a limit of 10,000.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me which port you are using to connect to SMTP server, because I am pretty much confident this is a config issue related to SMTP server.

Comment: I am not sure about this but it could be 7001.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is correct, because 25 or 2525 or 587 or 465 are the commonly used smtp port numbers. Also, I still believe this is the issue of threshold[limit for addresses in a single email, not limit for email count] getting crossed over. Please make sure your smtp server account support 1000 addresses.